# How to recursively update a same string?

Tags: postgresql, recursive

I have a table with a column containing names like this:

```
id, employee
1, Mr. John Cole Thornton
2, Mr. Paul George Mckenzie
3, Mr. George Mick McDoughal
4, Ms. Emily Suzan Flemming
5, Mr. Alan Bourdillion Traherne
```

I have a second table with a list of first names, like this

```
id, first_name
1, Emily
2, John
3, George
4, Suzan
5, Paul
6, Alan
7, Mary
8, Mick
9, Bourdillion
10, Jim
11, Cole
```

And I want to remove the first names in the first table, in order to obtain this:

```
id, employee
1, Mr. Thornton
2, Mr. Mckenzie
3, Mr. McDoughal
4, Ms. Flemming
5, Mr. Traherne
```

No matter how many first names, I would like to remove them all without calling several times my first_names table, and I wonder if this would be possible without using a loop in a function.

I have tried a query like this :

```
WITH RECURSIVE name AS (   SELECT REPLACE(t1.employee, t2.first_name, '') sec_name 
                        FROM  t1, t2 
                        WHERE position(t2.first_name in t1.employee) > 0 ) 
SELECT sec_name FROM name ;
```

But I get as many output as there are first names in the input, like :

```
Id, sec_name
1, John Thornton
1, Cole Thornton
2, Paul Mckenzie
2, George Mckenzie
...
```

My Postgres version is 9.6 .

Any help will be much appreciated !

Comment: Your CTE is NOT recursive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
    SELECT employee, 1 id
    FROM t1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT REPLACE(employee, first_name, ''), id+1
    FROM cte
    JOIN t2 USING (id)
)
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(employee, ' +', ' ') employee
FROM cte 
WHERE id > ( SELECT MAX(id) 
             FROM t2 )
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=4715c6c76ee8ae3ccce9004017ad126a)

If `t2.id` values do not start with 1 or have omissions, you must re-enumerate `t2` records in CTE using ROW_NUMBER().

---

**UPDATE.**

Possible problem - some `first_name` is a substring of some `employee` (John and Johnson, for example). If so use spaces as additional wrappers:

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
SELECT employee || ' ' employee, 1 id
FROM t1
UNION ALL
SELECT REPLACE(employee, ' ' || first_name || ' ', ' '), id+1
FROM cte
JOIN t2 USING (id)
)
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(employee, ' +', ' ') employee
FROM cte 
WHERE id > ( SELECT MAX(id) 
             FROM t2 )
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=51646d492eb9d196bc8e1d14c2ddb4ee)

PS. Trim excess trailing space if needed.

Comment: this seems fantastic but currently I'm not able to test your solution with my real data.  I'll do it tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

You may use `regexp_replace` with first names presented in an alternation,
to be replaced by an empty string. No recursivity is needed in that case.

The model is:

```
SELECT regexp_replace(fullname,
  '\m(firstname1|firstname2|firstname3|...)\M ', -- note the ending space!
   '',
   'g')
from...
```

`\m` and `\M` match at word boundaries, ensuring that partial name matches don't occur.
The space at the end is meant to avoid matching the last name if it happens to
coincide with a first name in the list. It also works when there is a single first name rather than two, even if your sample data has always two.

If there is any chance that first names might contain non-alphabetic
characters that are special to regular expressions, they'd need to be
quoted with backslashes, like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION quote_meta(text) RETURNS text AS $$
  select regexp_replace($1, '([\[\]\\\^\$\.\|\?\*\+\(\)])', '\\\1', 'g');
$$ language sql strict immutable;
```

Then the alternation can be formed by aggregating all first names like this:

```
SELECT string_agg(quote_meta(first_name), '|') FROM table
```

Finally a global update in your table could plausibly be done in a single pass by combining the above pieces into a query like this:

```
WITH replacement AS (
 SELECT id,
     regexp_replace(employee,
        concat (
          '\m(',
          (SELECT string_agg(quote_meta(first_name), '|') FROM table_first_name),
          ')\M ' -- note the ending space!
     ),
     '',
     'g') AS newval
   FROM table_employees
)
UPDATE table_employees
   SET employee = newval
  FROM replacement
 WHERE replacement.id = table_employees.id
   AND employee <> newval;
```

Warning: this is untested.

Comment: Thank you@Daniel Vérité, this is very interesting and works as well.  I'll need some more time and test it further in other contexts.